# Pointcast Alternatives?

Tags: screensaver, rss, feed

I used to love Pointcast in the early days of the internet.

It was a screensaver that, like RSS feeds, brought in all your favorite sources with news articles, stock quotes, and various other info, turning it into a visually interesting screensaver. It was well before widespread broadband availability, and I heard so many workplaces banned it that the company eventually folded.

I wonder if there are any modern-day equivalents?

I certainly have feed readers and some awesome desktop gadgets that bring in various things like news and weather, and I don't want a whole screensaver like pointcast. But I wondered if anyone out there had other suggestions worth taking a look at; making some kind of feed display of interest, or some other way to turn favorite content into more animated desktop background, etc...